# Cutting Stock Optimization:Finding all Possible combinations in R

Tags: r

I am looking at the cutting stock problem as described [here](https://neos-guide.org/content/cutting-stock-problem). Now the starting point of the problem is where they say for the given possible cuts namely 14,31,36,45 a plank of length 100 can be cut into 37 possible patterns. One pattern can be 1,0,1,1, while another can be 1,1,0,1 or 0,0,0,2 etc. Is there an existing algorithm which can be used in R that will list down all possible combinations for a given over all size and individual cuts in this case 37

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute force approach. Create a vector that has the "max" for each cut. Then create a grid of possibilities. Then do matrix multiplication on the grid against the cuts to get the total "length" of the combination -- anything less than or equal to (lteq) 100 is "legit". Noting there are 38 combinations because one case is 0,0,0,0 which you probably want to throw out.

```
cuts <- c(14, 31, 36, 45)
# Get the max number of each length of cut
max_of_each <- floor(100 / cuts)  

possibilities <- lapply(max_of_each, function(i) seq(0, i))
grid_possibilities <- expand.grid(possibilities)
idx_lteq_100 <- as.matrix(grid_possibilities) %*% cuts <= 100

grid_possibilities[idx_lteq_100, ]
nrow(grid_possibilities[idx_lteq_100, ])
# [1] 38
```